# Cache Not updating for MCS Lock in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, caching, locking, volatile

I'm getting some really odd cache behavior for an MCS Lock in Java. Basically, it will work for up to four threads (the number of cores on my machine), but will get stuck for more. When I debug, I see that the program is getting stuck on the line

```
while (qnode.locked);
```

Inside of the lock() function. When debugging, I can see that one of the thread's QNode has locked set to false, but I'm guessing that's because the debugger causes the cache to update. I just threw "volatile" onto all variables as a desperate attempt to no avail. Here's the class that I'm using:

```
class MCSLock
{
private volatile AtomicReference<QNode> tail;
private volatile ThreadLocal<QNode> myNode;

public MCSLock()
{
    tail = new AtomicReference<QNode>(null);
    myNode = new ThreadLocal<QNode>()
            {
                protected QNode initialValue() { return new QNode(); }
            };
}

public void lock()
{
    QNode qnode = myNode.get();
    QNode pred = tail.getAndSet(qnode);
    if (pred != null)
    {
        qnode.locked = true;
        pred.next = qnode;
        while (qnode.locked);
    }
}

public void unlock()
{
    QNode qnode = myNode.get();
    if (qnode.next == null)
    {
        if (tail.compareAndSet(qnode, null)) return;
        while (qnode.next == null);
    }
    qnode.next.locked = false;
    qnode.next = null;
}

private class QNode
{
    volatile boolean locked = false;
    volatile QNode next = null;
}
}
```

Comment: Does it work if you change `QNode` to use an `AtomicBoolean` and an `AtomicReference`?

Comment: I don't know nearly enough about concurrency in Java to be able to say with confidence what's going on, and i suspect that's true of almost everyone on SO. You might like to take this to the [concurrency-interest](http://altair.cs.oswego.edu/mailman/listinfo/concurrency-interest) mailing list, where the great and the good of the Java concurrency world gather.

Comment: @msandiford Sadly, it does not :(

Comment: Just tested it, and it works OK for me up to 10 thread.  Can you post your failing test code as well?  Which JDK are you using?

Comment: @msandiford My test code is fairly lengthy, but this is the general idea: count 1 to 1200000 using n threads where n goes from 1 to 6. If you don't use a large number, or you don't have enough contention, then the code will probably work. The idea here is to make sure it works under stress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works! However, my guess is that your system isn't good enough to do >4 threads quickly.

Running on a dual-core i5, execution hung on 5 threads

Running on a quad-core overclocked i7, execution completed on 5 threads as expected. Woo!

Comment: This is a good comment to help to confirm what the asker suspected. However this doesn't answer the the implied question of how to make the project work with only 4 active threads available. Consider relocating this as a comment on the question.

Comment: Hmm, okay that's odd. Thanks for double checking it for me! I ran it on my machine with an OC'd i5 at 4.6 GHz, so something odd must be going on here. Maybe i7's have better, more consistent cache behavior? Oh well, at least it's not my fault :)

Answer (score 1):

I have got the same problem. There is a small error into unlock() method. Before setting the false value into locked variable for the next node we need to wait untill this value gets true into lock method.
I added

```
 
while (!qnode.next.locked) {}
```

before

```
    qnode.next.locked = false;
```

into unlock() method and the problem ran away!

Comment: It's been a looong time since I last used Java, but I don't think that should be necessary. Inside of the `lock` function, `pred.next` isn't set until after `qnode.locked` is set to true. I.e. spinning on `qnode.next == null` *should* do the trick. This is, of course, working on my assumption that `volatile` guarantees sequential consistency in Java (which, IIRC it does). I.e. those two operations can't occur out of order as a result of optimizations

Answer (score 0):

`while (qnode.locked);` doesn't do anything as far as i can see . Maybe you mean

```
    do {
        pred.next = qnode;
        // update qnode
       } while (qnode.locked);
```

Comment: No, that part works. The idea is to spin on that Thread's QNode. The volatile keyword should force the cache to update. I've already tried a similar approach and like I said, it works for up to and including 4 threads

Comment: Usually the construct is `while(!available) {lock.wait();}` but your code is not giving up the lock.  If your building your own lock implementation I would suggest to subclass AbstractQueuedSynchronizer and use it as a helper class.

Comment: The point of this is to implement an MCS lock. The syntax, etc. is correct, Java is just not updating the cache. Also, why would you use a lock to implement a lock???